# How do I generalize this transformation of a distribution to non-discrete distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose I have a distribution $D$, a function $f$, and another distribution $D_f$. Suppose I want to transform $D$ to a similar distribution $D'$ such that for $X \sim D'$ it holds that the distribution of $f(X)$ is $D_f$. If $D$ is discrete, I may define $D'$ as follows
$$
D'(x) = E_{y \sim D_f}[P_D[x | f(x) = y]]
$$
and this will have the desired property.

Is there a nice way to generalize this to general distributions that will be correctly defined? I am having some measurability issues when the distribution is not discrete.

Essentially, the issue is that if the distribution is not discrete, then the probabilities are zero. At the same time, I cannot just easily ask about the probability of a measurable set under $D'(x)$ because then in the definition, I compute $f(x)$ and it is not clear what to do when I am dealing with a set of elements and not just one element $x$.